# Magento get total pages in search result

Tags: php, magento

Hi I want to get number of pages in search result, this is how I get results:

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

In this way I get current page:

```
$current_page = Mage::getBlockSingleton('page/html_pager')->getCurrentPage();
```

But how to get number of all pages, and link to another page (I want  to do a image 'next' after products results)

If I do `echo $_productCollection->getSize();` I get number of item on a single page...

Answer (score 1):

First you need to calculate total size of your collection by following code:-

Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection()->getSize();

Then you can divide this size by the value of products which you are going to show on a page.SO you will have the total number of pages.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getProductCollection() on a non-objec

Comment: Please use the right spelling of catalog, I have written wrong one and now I have updated

Comment: Ohhh sorry !Please following one-
Mage::getSingleton('catalogsearch/layer')->getProductCollection()->getSize();

Comment: Because it is search page , so we need to catalog search model instead of catalog. Previously I didn't focus on it

Answer (score 0):

In the block (`Mage_Page_Block_Html_Pager`) you have a method `getTotalNum()`.

So in the template (`frontend\yourpackage\yourtheme\template\page/html/pager.phtml`) you can use:

```
$this->getTotalNum()
```

If you want the count in `result.phtml` template you can use:

```
$this->getResultCount()
```

Comment: but I'm not in this block, I need it in the result.phtml